# Can two processes share same page, in case that the other page isn't "full"?

Tags: memory, memory-management, cpu, cpu-architecture, hardware

If I have a process which needs 6KB of RAM and the page size is 4KB, I need to allocate two pages. Can another PROCESS access the remaining 2KB for himself, so that two processes share same page table?

Comment: OSes don't do that because there'd be no memory protection to stop one process from stepping on the other.  If you don't care about robustness and both processes are owned by the same user, uh I guess maybe.  They wouldn't share the same page *table*, though, just the physical page.

Answer (score 0):

> Can two processes share same page, in case that the other page isn't "full"?

In theory it is possible, but there are significant issues:

- As @Peter says, allowing both processes to share the same page would bypass traditional process memory protections, as for most processors access protection granularity would be no smaller than a whole page.
- The two processes would have to coordinate in some way about who gets what part of that shared page.  This could range from

  - simple coordination that says, process 1 gets the first half and process 2 gets the 2nd half — but this becomes silly when process 1 or process 2 needs more memory, since at that point probably would have been better off simply having their own pages.
  - the processes communicate with each other to formalize a split between who gets what of that page.  Such communication would typically be some kind of synchronization, which is a bottleneck for many situations.

    Consider multiple threads in the same process — some modern runtime systems, e.g. for Java and C#, provide a separate per-thread heap so that simple memory allocations do not require synchronization with other threads.

Having one page that is not full represents less than a page of waste per process, which is not very high overhead, so not really a problem that needs solving, given the issues of security and coordination.

Effectively, the operating systems already share the whole of physical memory between processes albeit at a page granularity, so there is sharing (just not intra-page sharing) and the amount of waste is bounded.

Comment: I was picturing something like loading the `.text` of one tiny executable into the start of a page, and the `.text` of another into the end of the same page.  (Or the end of a section of one into the start of a physical page, and the start of a section of another into the end of the same physical page.  With position-independent code for at least the 2nd.)  With `.text` sections, they'd even be mapped read-only so they couldn't interfere.  Or do copy-on-write with `.data`/`.bss` and the break, but that's likely to actually need to copy so it's silly for memory regions that could grow.